# stretching text field with button to fill parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div `<div id="ab">` which contain a text field `<input type="text" class="a" />` and a submit button `<input type="submit" value="Test" class="b" />`. The div has fixed height and have length 100%. Text field have specific height. Submit button have specific height only. I want Text field to stretch the entire div (in width) leaving space for the submit button to dock. Setting width in percentage is not working;

**styling;**

```
#ab{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    border: solid 1px #999999;
}
#ab .a{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    height: 34px;
}
#ab .b{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

**html;**

```
<div id="ab">
  <input type="text" class="a" />
  <input type="submit" value="Test" class="b" />
</div>
```

I am getting this;

[image]

and I want this;

[image]

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/7EvQn/)** is the fiddle.

How can I do this using css?

Comment: setting percentage values seem to work for me, [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/TUHAa/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to achiev this is giving #ab a fixed width. Then it's pure math.

Or you do this:

```
#ab .a{
    width:100%; /* << */
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    height: 34px;
}
#ab .b{
    margin: 0 0 0 -100px; /* << */
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

Additionally also apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.a` if you want its width to include optional paddings.

```
.a { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Comment: That is not really a solution, because the button covers now the right part of the textbox

Answer (score 2):

You can realize that with a table

html

```
<div id="ab">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <td><input type="text" class="a" /></td>
         <td class="right"><input type="submit" value="Test" class="b" /></td>
     </tr>        
  </table> 
</div>
```

css

```
#ab{
background-color: #CCCCCC;
height: 36px;
border: solid 1px #999999;
width: 100%;
}
table{
    width:100%;      
}
.right{
    width:100px;
}
#ab .a{
    display: block;
    border: none;
    height: 34px;
    width:100%;
}
#ab .b{
    display: block;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: this is bad practice, since tables should not be used for layout(!)

Comment: But let's face it. We are talking her about form fields. There is no better way to layout the appearance of form fields anyway. For general layout I am on your side

Comment: excuse, but this is absolutely rubbish. to layout forms i use lists with contained floating controls. if i do this on a grid sheet reference, i can get pixel-perfect, or fluid layout forms that renders perfect.

Comment: just to be constructive - [here's how](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Styling_forms).

Comment: As you perfectly said: you use. That's your personal thing and I do mine. I see form inputs as a form of data. That means a presentation within a table is absolutely valid and conform. If you see that as rubbish is your thing. But to stay in the semantic, presenting forms in lists is not really the right use of lists either. Or?

Comment: correct, but the list semantics are closer - (i see) forms as lists of prompt data, and the W3C is backing me up. anyway sorry if i offended you - this, of course, is no rubbish - just a different opinion.

Comment: I'm not offended. I'm totally fine. Everyone has his own style and everyone including me does in his professional fields things to make it work. The result is for the customer in the end more important than the way. I respect your view and find it for sure interesting, because I never thought about going over lists for that approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have the button at 100px and not variable (with percents) then there isn't a way to do it with pure CSS. You can't say width: (100%-100px), so I would suggest setting it with Jquery:

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jesseclark/rXKqv/